# Why different versions of the same nupkg are not restored in solution folder?

Tags: windows, uwp, nuget

In my solution, I have two projects, one refer to a nuget package v1.0, another refers to the same nuget package v2.0.

In MyProject.nuget.props, I see this:

$(UserProfile).nuget\packages\

And I thought when I run command "nuget restore" it should restore both versions to above location: $(UserProfile).nuget\packages\, actually it did. And then also restore to my project folder/packages. But I find after restoring, there is only v1.0 under my project folder/package, and hence the project refers to v2.0 cannot build correctly.

Can we refer two different versions of the same package in the same solution for two projects?

Comment: sorry, does your project had `packages.json`? could you check that your project actually uses the nuget properly? by rights, you did not need to copy over from `$(UserProfile).nuget\packages\` to the project folder. Visual Studio should handle that already.

Comment: If you are using a project.json file or a .NET Core sdk style project then the packages will not be copied to your solution/project when restoring the packages. They will be used at compile time. If you are using a packages.config file then the NuGet package files will be restored into a folder inside your solution directory, typically called packages..

Comment: Project 1 is a win32 project, must use v1.0 of that nupkg. Project 2 is a UWP project, it uses v2.0 of that nupkg.

Comment: Under my user profile nuget packages, both versions are there. But under my solution packages, only v1.0 is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why different versions of the same nupkg are not restored in solution folder?

This depends on the nuget management method used by your project, `packages.config`, `packages.json` or `PackageReference`.

The default nuget packages folder for `packages.config` is in solution folder `packages`.

The default nuget packages folder for `packages.json` or `PackageReference` is global packages `$(UserProfile).nuget\packages\`

So your win32 project should use the `packages.config` and UWP project should use the `PackageReference`.

Note: Check the `PackageReference`, edit your project file `.csproj`, you will find following code:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xxxx" Version="x.x.x" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

> Can we refer two different versions of the same package in the same
>   solution for two projects?

Yes, you can create two projects with the same nuget management method.